# can't upload images via FileTransfer plugin of ionic 3 to Cloudinary

Tags: ionic-framework, file-upload, ionic3, file-transfer, cloudinary

I'm trying to upload images from mobile gallery to cloudinary.
I have followed the logic in documentation of uploading photos from angular to cloudinary that I found in [this link](https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_angular/blob/master/samples/photo_album/app/js/photo-album/photo-upload.component.ts).

And I used [`File Transfer`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/file-transfer/) plugin to upload photos from ionic3 app to cloudinary.

this is the `upload()` function :

```
upload() {
    const fileTransfer: FileTransferObject = this.transfer.create();
    let options: FileUploadOptions = {
        fileKey: 'testName',
        fileName: 'test',
        mimeType : "text/plain",
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest' },
        params:{upload_preset:'preset'}
    };
    let url = 'https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/<cloud_name>/image/upload';
    if (this.imageURI) {
        fileTransfer.upload(this.imageURI[0], encodeURI(url), options)
                .then((data) => {
                    console.log('uploaded heeere data', JSON.stringify(data))
                }, (err) => {
                    console.log('errorrrr', JSON.stringify(err))
                })
    }
}
```

`this.imageUri[0]` is a photo as base 64

and in `app.module.ts` I have specified the `cloudinary` configuration :

```
 import { CloudinaryConfiguration, CloudinaryModule } from "@cloudinary/angular-5.x";
 import { Cloudinary } from "cloudinary-core";


@NgModule({
declarations: [....],
imports: [
BrowserModule,
HttpClientModule,
CloudinaryModule.forRoot({Cloudinary}, {
      cloud_name: "<cloud_name>",
      upload_preset: 'preset',
      api_key:'<api_key>'
  } as CloudinaryConfiguration),
]
.......
})
```

But I failed to upload.
There's no error shown.. Just a message: `File Name is too long`

I don't know if the connection is established or not and is it `cloudinary` who's refusing files with long names or what?

Could some one please help me how to debug to see where the problem is? or could someone help me fixing this?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

you should send image name not base64 encode ,the server read the base64 as name file ,so you try should send file name in first parameter

Comment: But I set `  fileName: 'test'` in the `options` .. isn't correct?

Comment: no, you did not define extension for exemple :test.png ,also in first argument you should pass image path not base64 as you see on doc : fileTransfer.upload('<file path>', '<api endpoint>', options)